# MySQL filter general_log

Tags: mysql, triggers, filter, logging

I am on a very active server and would like to keep certain repetitive queries from being placed in the log table.

I have tried making a trigger on the mysql.general_log table, but it appears that its not possible to make triggers in the mysql database. ( And if by chance the MySQL decides to log the trigger, then it having the trigger would defeat that purpose as well. )

Comment: Not possible I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not possible I'm afraid. – Mchl Jan 7
>   at 22:27

Mchl Seems to have the best answer in my comment. To bad I can't mark a comment as solved. :P